# Why does Themekit shows "Skipped" message and it won't update the live server or the Shopify theme that is being currently worked on?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify, shopify-template, visual-web-developer, shopify-liquid

I am currently creating an additional FAQ page in a Shopify template and I'm running Themewatch to watch for changes in my VS Code editor, my issue is that I am not seeing the changes I make to Shopify template in the actual development store that I'm currently working on, the message in my terminal shows "Skipped", Does anyone know how I can get my page to appear in the shopify store that I am working on?

I restarted my computer, logged out & logged back in to Shopify, cleared my browser cache, made sure I am working on the correct theme (it is the Debut version 17.14.1), created another page (a contact-page) and that one did show up, but I still cannot get the "FAQ" page I created to show up in the Shopify back-end.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to check if the page you are previewing is using the template that you are currently working on?